# Expanding a temporary slice if more bytes are needed

Tags: file, go, slice

I'm generating random files programmatically in a directory, *at least* `temporaryFilesTotalSize` worth of random data (a bit more, who cares).

Here's my code:

```
var files []string

    for size := int64(0); size < temporaryFilesTotalSize; {
        fileName := random.HexString(12)
        filePath := dir + "/" + fileName
        file, err := os.Create(filePath)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        size += rand.Int63n(1 << 32) // random dimension up to 4GB
        raw := make([]byte, size)
        _, err := rand.Read(raw)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        file.Write(raw)
        file.Close()
        files = append(files, filePath)
    }
```

Is there any way I can avoid that `raw := make([]byte, size)` allocation in the for loop?
Ideally I'd like to keep a slice on the heap and only grow if a bigger `size` is required. Any way to do this efficiently?

Comment: Why do you want to? Is the performance overhead of a _single_ memory allocation greater than that of file I/O on your target platform?

Comment: To reuse the `raw` slice, move it outside the for loop. Inside the loop slice it as you need: `tempRaw := raw[:size]`. Allocate a bigger if `len(raw) < size`.

Comment: Also note that if you're worried about performance, you can do this without using an intermediate buffer. `os.File` implements `io.ReaderFrom`, so you could create an `io.LimitedReader` from `rand.Rand` and pass that to `File.ReadFrom()`.

Comment: But as @Thomas noted: generating random data and writing that to disk is an order of magnitude slower (at least) than allocating a contiguous memory for buffer.

Comment: @icza `ReaderFrom` and `LimitReader` are excellent suggestions. Make it an answer and I'll accept it. It's a WAY better method to do this.

Comment: @Dean There you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should know that generating random data and writing that to disk is at least an order of magnitude slower than allocating a contiguous memory for buffer. This definitely falls under the "premature optimization" category. Eliminating the creation of the buffer inside the iteration will not make your code noticeably faster.

#### Reusing the buffer

But to reuse the buffer, move it outside of the loop, create the biggest needed buffer, and slice it in each iteration to the needed size. It's OK to do this, because we'll overwrite the whole part we need with random data.

Note that I somewhat changed the `size` generation (likely an error in your code as you always increase the generated temporary files, since you use the `size` accumulated size for new ones).

Also note that writing a file with contents prepared in a `[]byte` is easiest done using a single call to [`os.WriteFile()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#WriteFile).

Something like this:

```
bigRaw := make([]byte, 1 << 32)

for totalSize := int64(0); ; {
    size := rand.Int63n(1 << 32) // random dimension up to 4GB
    totalSize += size
    if totalSize >= temporaryFilesTotalSize {
        break
    }

    raw := bigRaw[:size]
    rand.Read(raw) // It's documented that rand.Read() always returns nil error

    filePath := filepath.Join(dir, random.HexString(12))
    if err := os.WriteFile(filePath, raw, 0666); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    files = append(files, filePath)
}
```

### Solving the task without an intermediate buffer

Since you are writing big files (GBs), allocating that big buffer is not a good idea: running the app will require GBs of RAM! We could improve it with an inner loop to use smaller buffers until we write the expected size, which solves the big memory issue, but increases complexity. Luckily for us, we can solve the task without any buffers, and even with decreased complexity!

We should somehow "channel" the random data from a [`rand.Rand`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#Rand) to the file *directly*, something similar what [`io.Copy()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy) does. Note that `rand.Rand` implements [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader), and [`os.File`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File) implements [`io.ReaderFrom`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReaderFrom), which suggests we could simply pass a `rand.Rand` to `file.ReadFrom()`, and the `file` itself would get the data directly from `rand.Rand` that will be written.

This sounds good, but the `ReadFrom()` reads data from the given reader until EOF or error. Neither will ever happen if we pass `rand.Rand`. And we do know how many bytes we want to be read and written: `size`.

To our "rescue" comes [`io.LimitReader()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#LimitReader): we pass an `io.Reader` and a size to it, and the returned reader will supply no more than the given number of bytes, and after that will report EOF.

Note that creating our own `rand.Rand` will also be faster as the source we pass to it will be created using [`rand.NewSource()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#NewSource) which returns an "unsynchronized" source (not safe for concurrent use) which in turn will be faster! The source used by the default/global `rand.Rand` is synchronized (and so safe for concurrent use–but is slower).

Perfect! Let's see this in action:

```
r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().Unix()))

for totalSize := int64(0); ; {
    size := r.Int63n(1 << 32)
    totalSize += size
    if totalSize >= temporaryFilesTotalSize {
        break
    }

    filePath := filepath.Join(dir, random.HexString(12))
    file, err := os.Create(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if _, err := file.ReadFrom(io.LimitReader(r, fsize)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err = file.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    files = append(files, filePath)
}
```

Note that if `os.File` would not implement `io.ReaderFrom`, we could still use `io.Copy()`, providing the file as the destination, and a limited reader (used above) as the source.

Final note: closing the file (or any resource) is best done using `defer`, so it'll get called no matter what. Using `defer` in a loop is a bit tricky though, as deferred functions run at the end of the enclosing function, and not at the end of the loop's iteration. So you may wrap it in a function. For details, see [`defer` in the loop - what will be better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617758/defer-in-the-loop-what-will-be-better/45620423#45620423)